# Do I need a visa for the United Kingdom if I fly to Heathrow via BA and from Heathrow to South Africa via virgin

Tags: uk, transit, transit-visas, lhr, south-african-citizens

Do I need a visa for the United Kingdom if I fly from Hamburg, Germany to Heathrow via BA and from Heathrow to South Africa via Virgin.

I will not leave the airport, I'm a South African citizen which requires a visa when entering the UK.

Do I need a visa if I book the tickets separately 
Do I need a visa if I book the tickets together on a site like flugladen.de?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to apply for a Transit Visa, regardless of whether you pass through the border control or not. You may be exempt if you have:

a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)

a residence permit issued by Australia or New Zealand

a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland

a resident permit issued by Canada after 28 June 2002

a uniform format category D visa for entry into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland

an Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section)

a Schengen Approved Destination Scheme (ADS) group tourism visa where the holder is travelling to the Schengen country that issued the visa

a flight ticket from the Schengen area, if you can prove that you entered the Schengen area in the previous 30 days on the basis of a valid Schengen ADS visa

a valid USA I-551 Temporary Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp version will not be accepted)

a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998

an expired USA I-551 Permanent Residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998, with a valid I-797 letter authorising extension

a valid standalone US Immigration Form 155A/155B issued by the USA (attached to a sealed brown envelope)

You can check for yourself in https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: User Neusser already linked to a question that contains all of this information in an answer. We try to maintain that page as our canonical "Do I need a UK transit visa?" question, so there's only one place that needs to be updated if the rules change. We're very grateful that you've contributed an answer but it's best to concentrate your efforts on questions that haven't already been answered. Thanks, and we hope you enjoy the site and find it useful.